Are STL objects imported into Lumerical actually solid?
So I have written some code in python that generates some STLs from input masks. As I am interested in simulating the behavior of light in these structures I would like to import them into Lumerical. Lumerical has a STL import feature to help facilitate this, however, I am unsure whether the imported object will be solid or what is effectively a 'hollow' surface mesh. I would like it to be a solid object to be able to model light in the structure. The Lumerical help page for STL imports can be found here: https://optics.ansys.com/hc/en-us/articles/360034901953-STL-import-Simulation-object. On that webpage, the imported STLs are described to be 'treated as planar solid objects in the layout editor', however when I import an object in this way it appears like a shell in the CAD viewer.
Would anyone be able to shed anymore light on this? I wasn't able to find anything conclusive on whether STLs are supposed to be surface meshes or solid objects. If they are surface meshes is there anyway to 'fill' them in python so that when I import into Lumerical they appear as solid objects?
I have tried to find python packages to fill the STL objects and I have investigated whether the objects are solid in the Lumerical CAD viewer. I am aware there are many pieces of stand alone software that can be used to fill STL objects (e.g. meshmixer) but I'd prefer if I can do all of this in python...

Didn't pick tags silly. Read their descriptions carefully. Wheres your programming language is Python, you have picked the C++ tag [tag:STL].

From The definition: "an STL file uses a series of linked triangles (known as tessellation) to describe the surface geometry of a 3D design".
The file will only ever include the surface.
Since any collection of triangles can be defined, there is a big risk that someone will define triangles which don't form a closed surface. Also described as not being watertight. This means the mesh can't represent the surface of any shape and the mesh will need to be "repaired". There are many stl file repairing tools available.
